# Wierd Characters when PDF's printing with KENDO's Jquery Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, pdf-generation

I'm using Kendo's Grid for Jquery to develop a table with many columns. Including the buttons given by Kendo to print the table in .xlsx and .pdf, the problem is the PDF printer. Take a look at the PDF's doc properties:

[PDF properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfGvI.png)

I'm trying to delete this special characters ('Ã¾Ã¿') from the properties of the PDF generated. AT LEAST from the 'title' (título, in the last img). Here is my code:

**The 'page-template' used for the PDF:**

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="page-template">
<div class="page-template">
    <div class="header">
        <h3 align="center" style="margin: 1px;"><strong>Cuenta Corriente: Vista Composición</strong></h3>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: flex-start;">
            <p style="margin: 1px;">Cuenta Correntista: `v-cuit` , `v-desRazonSocial`.</p>
            <p style="margin: 1px;">Fechas Consulta: `vFdesde` al `vFhasta`.</p>
            <p style="margin: 1px;">Solicitado por: `AsamaUsuarios.ident_usua`.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Página #: pageNum # de #: totalPages #
    </div>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            noRecords: true, 
            messages: {
                commands: {
                  search: "Buscar..."
                }
            },
            toolbar: ["search","excel", "pdf"],
                excel: {
                        fileName: "ComposicionCtaCte.xlsx"
                    },
                pdf: {  
                        title: "Composicion Cta Cte",
                        fileName: "ComposicionCtaCte.pdf",
                        date: new Date(),
                        allPages: true,
                        avoidLinks: true,
                        template: $("#page-template").html(),
                        paperSize: ["525mm", "355mm"],
                        margin: {
                            top: "4.5cm",
                            left: "1cm",
                            right: "1cm",
                            bottom: "2cm",
                        },
                        landscape: true,
                        repeatHeaders: true,
                        scale: 1,
                    },
```

**Just to be clear:** The meta tag that specifies the charset = UTF-8 is already included in the source.

Comment: Could you specify the browser you're using? I'm unable to replicate in the Kendo-UI dojo using your exact configuration.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, version 91.0.4472.124.

Comment: I'd open up a bug report using the Telerik support. I'm unable to replicate using your exact configuration for that browser.